# Call Controller Method Which Return View With Ajax Call From Asp.net MVC View Page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor, view, response

i'm using .Net core 2.1 application, inside for loop how can i trigger controller view page without returning to ajax response,
see following code

> **this is my razor view**

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2"  onclick="SelectCategory(@item.CategoryId)">
                            <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                                <span class="icon"><span class="@item.Icon"></span></span>
                                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">@item.CategoryName</span>
                                <span class="number">32,891</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    }





<script>

        function SelectCategory(id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("ProductsList","Home")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { parentId: id }
            });
            
        }
    </script>




 public ActionResult ProductsList(int parentId)
        {
            List<PilCategory> all = new List<PilCategory>();
           
            if(parentId > 0)
                all = _context.PilCategory.Where(x=>x.ParentId == parentId).OrderBy(a => a.ParentId).ToList();
            else
                all = _context.PilCategory.OrderBy(a => a.ParentId).ToList();

            return View(all);
        }
```

pls someone help me, thaks for advance

Answer (score 2):

> how can i trigger controller view page without returning to ajax response

As far as I know, we couldn't trigger controller view page without returning to ajax response. Since the ajax will send the request to the controller view and the controller view will return the view as html response back to the ajax.

If we don't handle the response, that means current page will not change.

If you just want to pass the parentId to the ProductsList method, I suggest you could try to use `window.location`, this will make this page redirect to the ProductsList view which achieve refresh the whole page.

Notice: If we using ajax to call ProductsList, the whole page will not refresh. If we using `window.location`, it will redirect to another page or refresh the whole page.

More details about how to achieve this, you could refer to below codes:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function SelectCategory(id) {
            location.href = "/Home/ProductsList?parentId=" + id;
        }
    </script>
}
```

If you want to use ajax to achieve this, I suggest you could try to handle the response by using ajax success method. Normally, we will return the partial view in controller method and then we could add it into the html page by using jquery without refreshing the page.

More details about how to achieve this, you could  refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517565/7609093).